# A question about the common noun

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural, nouns, indefinite-article, writing

I wonder if the following sentence is missing something, isn't it?

["It's a long journey from tea leaf to cup of tea."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p3rAgR6bq_Q)

Shouldn't it be added an indefinite article or something before "tea leaf" and "cup of tea" ?

"It's a long journey from a tea leaf to a cup of tea." or
"It's a long journey from tea leaves to a cup of tea."

Answer (score 0):

The sentence isn't literal.  There isn't an actual journey. The sentence isn't  about the distance between a physical leaf and cup.  Instead this is figurative language, with "tea leaf" and "cup of tea" representing, metaphorically the starting and ending locations.

There are many stages from the situation "tea leaf" to the situation "cup of tea". The fact that these phrases are used to label situations, and don't refer to actual leaves or cups justifies the lack of an article.

Comment: Even it is figurative, aren't "tea leaf" and "cup of tea" still the common nouns and countable nouns? What grammatical rule is applied here?

Comment: You could compare proverbs like "many a slip 'twixt cup and lip", which can be said [with or without articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_many_a_slip_%27twixt_the_cup_and_the_lip), but omitting them maybe makes it sound more unusual or memorable or folksy or just short. It's commoner to use some nouns without an article than others with this kind of general sense, e.g. man and woman are used commonly as in "man is the most dangerous animal" but "the lion is the king of the jungle". Less a formal rule than just copying similar expressions.

Comment: There's also the "bean to cup" coffee machine (a snappy marketing term), which might be relevant to the specific case of tea.